# How to override func (l *Logger) Println(v ...interface{}) method golang?

Tags: go

How to override println method in golang?

> **`func (l *Logger) Println(v ...interface{})`**

Comment: Do you mean `fmt.Println()`? If so, I believe  the best you can do is create package that contains the same method and use that one instead of `fmt`.  As far as I know there is no way to overwrite base `fmt` package.

Comment: As others have said, overrides are not possible. However, if it's logging related, have a look at gitHub.com/sirupsen/logrus which supports log hooks which you can use to perform any customizations.

Comment: The line quoted is from an interface. Even in OO languages (which Go is not) you can't override methods of an interface, you can only implement them.

Answer (score 6):

> How to override ... [a] method golang?

Not at all. You simply cannot do this. Go does not provide *any* means of inheritance. Don't try, you will not succeed. You must use an other solution to your problem (which you did not state).